# Create Dynamic Javascript function using Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to create a javascript function dynamically from Angular2. I am using the code below to generate the javascript function, it creates the function without the name. Instead I need this javascript function to be created along with function name which would be called by some other javascript object.

The angular2 code which I am using to create the javascript function

```
var startPos = value.indexOf("{");
var endPos = value.lastIndexOf("}");
var body = value.substring(startPos + 1, endPos);
var args = "item";
value = new Function(args, body);
return value;
```

The dynamic function which is created

```
(function(item
/*``*/) {
return $.ig.formatter(new Date(item["WEEK_END_DT"]), 'date', "MM/dd/yyyy");
})
```

Instead I need the dynamic function as below

```
function myFunc(item) {
    return $.ig.formatter(new Date(item["WEEK_END_DT"]), 'date', "MM/dd/yyyy");
}
```

Note: myFunc function would be called by a third party control component i.e. IgniteUI - PivotGrid control. Currently I am getting the error message "myFunc is not defined". When I debugged the application, I could notice that the function is registered without a name as mentioned above.

Comment: But...your `value` variable will contain a reference to the function, so the function can be called as `value()`... What do you currently do with the result of the `return value` statement?

Comment: myFunc function would be called by a third party control component i.e. IgniteUI - PivotGrid control. Currently I am getting the error message "myFunc is not defined". When I debugged the application, i could notice that the function is registered without a name as mentioned in my query.

Comment: You didn't answer my question about what you're doing with the result of the `return value`. The return statement must be in a function that you haven't shown, so if that function is called, say, `createFunction()` then you could say something like `myFunc = createFunction(...)`.

Comment: I guess you're trying to programmatically declare a variable with a dynamic name that stores the function? If so, would it help if you assign the function as a property of an object accessible to the code that'll call that function?

e.g. `var functionLibrary = {}; ... functionLibrary[desiredFunctionName] = new Function(args, body)`? The new function can be called using `functionLibrary.desiredFunctionName()`

Comment: How come function name is important? It never is. myFunc is not defined may refer to global function or so. Btw, are there real evidences that eval is necessary here?

Comment: @nnnnnn, I tried returning the function with the return statement,   var myFunc1 = new Function("return " + value);
                            return myFunc1;  As a result it renders the following in the browser: (function() {
return function myFunc(item) {return $.ig.formatter(new Date(item["WEEK_END_DT"]), 'date', "MM/dd/yyyy");}
}); but still I am getting the same exception "myFunc is not defined", what is it I am missing here?